# Buildozer How can I solve "--ndk-api=21" error

Tags: python, android-ndk, kivy, buildozer

I have small app for Android that is kivy-python based.  To turn it into an APK I had to use buildozer.

When I run this final step:

`buildozer android debug deploy run`  I get this error.

I changed the NDK values in the spec files, or I changed codes. In short, what I did was looked at similar errors. I tried reported solutions and they didn't work.  I don't even know what the problem is.

Related logs :

```
[WARNING]: Missing executable: pkg-config is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed                                     
        [INFO]:    -> running autogen.sh
                   working: /home/abra/DeskException in thread background thread for pid 3917:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
            self.run()
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
            self._target(*self.args, **self._kwargs)
          File "/home/abra/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
          File "/home/abra/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
            handle_exit_code(exit_code)
          File "/home/abra/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
            return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
          File "/home/abra/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
            raise exc
        ErrorReturnCode_127: 

          RAN: /home/abra/Desktop/questionapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh

          STDOUT:
        /home/abra/Desktop/questionapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh: 2: exec: autoreconf: not found


          STDERR:


        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
            "_main_", fname, loader, pkg_name)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
            exec code in run_globals
          File "/home/abra/Desktop/questionapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1189, in <module>
            main()
          File "/home/abra/Desktop/questionapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1183, in main
            ToolchainCL()
          File "/home/abra/Desktop/questionapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 666, in _init_
            getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
          File "/home/abra/Desktop/questionapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 152, in wrapper_func
            build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
          File "/home/abra/Desktop/questionapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 205, in build_dist_from_args
            args, "ignore_setup_py", False
          File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 557, in build_recipes
          File "/home/abra/Desktop/questionapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/libffi/_init_.py", line 33, in build_arch
            shprint(sh.Command('./autogen.sh'), _env=env)
          File "pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 178, in shprint
          File "/home/abra/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 863, in next
            self.wait()
          File "/home/abra/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
            self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
          File "/home/abra/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
            raise exc
        sh.ErrorReturnCode_127: 

          RAN: /home/abra/Desktop/questionapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh

          STDOUT:
        /home/abra/Desktop/questionapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh: 2: exec: autoreconf: not found


          STDERR:

        # Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/abra/Desktop/questionapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21
        # 
        # Buildozer failed to execute the last command
        # The error might be hidden in the log above this error
        # Please read the full log, and search for it before
        # raising an issue with buildozer itself.
        # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: I see `autoreconf: not found`. Do you have `autoreconf`? Try running `which autoreconf`.

Comment: I dont have. I downloaded and tried still same error coming out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.If someone encounters this error I solved by following these steps

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt-get install autoconf

pip install --upgrade buildozer

sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5

pip3 install --user --upgrade cython virtualenv
```